# IzPack - XML generation after successful installation

Tags: xml, configuration, izpack

Greetings,

I am just starting with IzPack and I have a question for which I have not found anything online so far. Based on the user's input in a UserInputPanel I wish to generate an XML file at the end of the installation. This is going to be the configuration file used by my application upon startup. Is there a way to do this in IzPack? I'm quite confused after going through the documentaion. Do I need to write code for that or does IzPack provide some facility

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These methods might give you a lead in the right direction.

1) Either you copy a file to the installation directory (or elsewhere).
[Add file or directory](http://izpack.org/documentation/installation-files.html#file-add-files-or-directories)

2) You add a process panel that will execute a script after/before the panel and generate the xml file.
[Process Panels](http://izpack.org/documentation/panels.html#processpanel)

3) Add custom action at the installation phase.
[Custom actions](http://izpack.org/documentation/custom-actions.html#custom-actions-at-installing-time)